# Cruise Control.NET Disable Build Exception Emails

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have CruiseControl.NET setup to send out an email if there is a compile error and when the error has been fixed:

```
<notifications>
  <notificationType>Change</notificationType>
</notifications>
```

However this also sends out an email if the source code repository can't be reached. This is expected since the server is restarted every night.

How can I limit the alert emails to compile errors only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this also sends out an email if the source code repository can't be reached

You can use the **sourceControlErrorHandling** tag (action to take when a source control error occurs)

```
  <maxSourceControlRetries>3</maxSourceControlRetries>
  <sourceControlErrorHandling>ReportOnRetryAmount</sourceControlErrorHandling>
```

Setting **ReportOnRetryAmount** to a high value will lower your exception build email.

*Reference: 'Project Configuration Block' documentation.*
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Configuration_Block

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CC.NET is able to distinguish a "usual" build failure from source code unavailability. The notification type can be one of the following: `{'Always', 'Change', 'Failed', 'Success', 'Fixed', 'Exception'}`. I'm not sure I can tell the difference between `Failed` and `Exception` - probably, the first is a build failure, including unit test failure, etc., while the other one refers to the CC.NET own code failure.

Anyway, if I were you, I would do one of the following:

- experiment with notification types (just in case)
- make sure the build process is not triggered when the server is restarting, e.g. if you configured nightly builds, you can schedule those to run after the server restarts